# Изменение URL во время загрузки

Tags: веб-программирование, url, webbrowser, браузер

Есть страница, которая отображается в браузере. Страница вызывается из одного десктопного приложения – запускается стандартный браузер системы.

Страница не наша, нашего партнера, но партнер не может ее под наши потребности изменить. Страница может принимать один параметр, который дожен подменяться на другой, мною определенный.

Я не веб программист, но мне кажется, что url можно как-то изменять и вызывать загрузку еще раз. Т.е. необходимо какими-то средствами определить адрес, если он соответсвет определенному шаблону изменить параметр и загрузить страницу еще раз.

Еще раз, я не веб прораммист, поэтому на вскидку из своих скудных знаний приходит в голову сдедующее:
Может быть создать свою веб страницу, контейнер для страницы с ява скриптом. Ява скрипт как-то делат описанную работу.

Как вы думаете, возможно такое? Поможете с наброском?

Comment: Возможно подойдёт history API для js. Сменить URL Реально. Но из вопроса не сильно понятно.

Comment: Поясню на примере. Когда загружается страница она имеет опеределенный URL, например „myaddresse.ru/index…&prm1=value1&prm2=value2“. Нужно подменить параметр prm2 на другое значение и загрузить страницу с новый парметром:
„myaddresse.ru/index…&prm1=value1&prm2=custom_value“
Может получится так, что пользователь перейдет по ссылке на другую страницу, а затем оттуда вернется обратно (но не через кнопки браузера НАЗАД, а через линки на эту страницу). Нужно поймать этот момент и подменить параметр снова.